# Align multiline text vertically center next to span icon

Tags: html, css, uikit

I have this code:
Im using `UIKIT` for the styling.

```html
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.15.24/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />

<!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.15.24/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.15.24/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>


<div class="uk-inline uk-text-small">
        <b>Jelle Botman</b><br/>
        My Company
        <span class="uk-icon-button uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="user"></span>
        <div uk-dropdown>
            <a href=''>Profiel</a><br/>
            <a href=''>Uitloggen</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I would like to have this:
The text vertically centered in the middle next to the icon.
[image]

Problems:

- Text is not vertically aligned in the middle
- The line break between my name and the company is to high

I tried `vertical-align: middle` but that didn't fix my problem.
How can I achieve this without big modifications to my `html` structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a class `user-card` in order to add custom CSS and use
[flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to help
solving your problem. Then put the user text into a container, here I put
it in a `<span class="user">`. This will be the left cell.

As flexbox will display the childs as cells, I added a new `<span>` around the
icon and the dropdown menu. This will be the right cell.

And to be HTML compliant I replaced the dropdown `<div>` by a `<span>` as you
are normally not allowed to put a "block" type of element into an "inline" type
of element.

Replaced `<b>` by `<strong>` to be HTML compliant too.

```html
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.15.24/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />

<!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.15.24/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.15.24/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

.user-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  column-gap: 0.5em;
  align-content: center;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.user-card .user {
  text-align: right;
}

.user-card .uk-icon-button {
  border: 1px solid;
}

</style>

<div class="uk-inline uk-text-small user-card">
  <span class="user">
    <strong>Jelle Botman</strong><br />
    My Company    
  </span>
  <span>
    <span class="uk-icon-button uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="user"></span>
    <span uk-dropdown>
      <a href=''>Profiel</a><br />
      <a href=''>Uitloggen</a>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```